# VBA Static Variable Missed?

Tags: vba

I am developing a program that tries to make users more convenient, what I did as below

1. declare a User Defined Type(p_typeRunClass) which can store the initialed Class
2. Initial the clsEHDBClass(which builds up DB connection, and gets data from DB, OK)
3. Get data from MSSQL and put data into an array(static array, OK).
4. Build an Excel OLEObject.ComboBox, and set the .list=DataArray as mentioned last item(OK).

At first, everything is okay, but after the OLEObject has been load data over 3 times or more, the DataArray(static) is gone. And also the static User Defined Type(p_typeRunClass) is gone too.

I have tried several times to figure out what's going wrong, and I got below.

And, if I rewrite the program to replace the OLEObject from ComboBox to DropDown Object, the program will be fine.
Unfortunately, the "DropDown" function can't meet my requirement.

If anyone knows what's going wrong?
Any reply will be grateful!
[image: VBA Bugs? Static Variable missed?]

Comment: "Build an Excel OLEObject.ComboBox" might need to expand a bit on this.  Anything which resets your VB project or triggers a re-compilation will clear Global/Static variables, so it seems likely that something in your code is doing that.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for your reply, but not every time the "Reset" will happened, it seems very very strange......Once I open the Variables Monitor Windows to check the variables, and things back to normal......

Comment: You can enable notifications before state loss. VBE >> Tools >> Options >> General >> Notify before state loss.

Comment: @KostasK. Thanks! As you mentioned, just like you say, I always keep "Notify Before State Loss" enabled. But as Tim Williams advises, I remove some code sections that set  ComboBox.List from the sub, and it became normal. Even though, I still can't find the root cause. BTW, thank you all!

Comment: Yeah, that's only for debugging. It should be disabled in production code.